# jquery onload visibility issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

This is an issue that has been bugging me for sometime, but i have always brushed it under the carpet. When you refresh the browser on [my site - click here](http://www.lybstore.com/index.php/store/view) I noticed the visibility of my show and hide menu's are visible for about a second when the page is loading. I have set my CSS to `display: none` and also `visibility: hidden`  - i have tried both methods. Yet fail to overcome the problem. My question is how can this be avoided...

Below is a snippet of my show and hide functions...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();
        $('.show_hide').mouseenter(function(){
            $(".slidingDiv").slideDown();
            $(".slidingDiv").mouseleave(function(){
            $(".slidingDiv").slideUp();
            });
        });
     });     


$(function(){
        $(".drop-down-box").hide();
        $(".dropDown").show();
        $('.dropDown').click(function(){
            $(".drop-down-box").slideDown();
            $(".drop-down-box").mouseleave(function(){
            $(".drop-down-box").slideUp();
            });
        });
     });  


.slidingDiv{
height: 200px;
background-color: #000;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 52px;
z-index: 990;
visibility: visible;
    }

 .slidingDiv{
visibility: hidden;
  }



.active{
display: block;
   }

  .hidden-bits{
display: none;
 }
```

Comment: From your JS it looks like you're only hiding the element on document ready, but you say in your description that you're also hiding it in CSS. Can you post the CSS code where you do the hiding?

Comment: @JudeOsborn CSS has been added

Comment: You should consider cacheing your elements rather than selecting each line. Also, try using functional decomposition, you have repeated code which is a breeding ground for bugs.